# How to mount Ext3 on Windows Vista

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ext3

I had a Ubuntu12 on my PC but due to performance issue I turned back to Windows Vista ; Unfortunately I found that my other volume of 70Gb is not mounted because it's a Ext3 type and of course windows can't do it. 
I'm asking if there is a way to reuse this volume to exploit it.

Comment: wow. Vista performing better than Ubuntu? I've kept away from ubuntu since they started with the Unity interface, but one thing it's always been good at is performance.

Comment: ah yeah for my poor laptop of 5 years old it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use tools such as [ext2fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) or [ext2 IFS](http://www.fs-driver.org/)